# How to count elements with specific class jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have elements with classes like `dis_5` and `dis_3` .Here the `dis_` part remains same while the number changes . I want to count elements with each dis number eg if 3 elements have dis_5 class then count elements . Similarly for others dis_ also.

```
var result = $('[class^=dis_]').filter(function () {
            return this.class.match(/dis_\d+$/); //regex for the pattern "rank_ followed by a number"
    });
```

How to bundle together elements with specific number at end.

Comment: the jquery object has alength

Comment: I know length that's for count......How to fetch elements

Comment: You're most of the way there (but surely you meant `/dis_\d+$/` rather than `/rank_\d+/`?), just keep going.

Comment: You've said "classes like" but you're searching for and parsing IDs, not classes.

Comment: sorry, question was less clear before you showed your code

Comment: I want to count together elements with dis_3 together and others like dis_10

Comment: count together ... total, or individual counts - like `var result = Array.from($('[class^=dis_]')).map(e => e.className.match(/dis_\d+$/)).reduce((result, num) => (result[num] = (result[num] || 0) + 1, result), {});`

Comment: @JaromandaX `.map()` call is not necessary

Comment: @guest271314 - no, it isn't - why don't **you** show me how **you** would do it

Comment: Before OP mentioned `html` at comment `Array.from($("[class^=dis_]")).reduce(o, el) { o[el.className)] = $("[class*="+el.className.replace(/dis_/, "")+]").length; return o }, {})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
var classes={};
$('[class^=dis_]').each(function () {
    if(classes.hasOwnProperty(this.className)){
      classes[this.className]= classes[this.className]+1;
    } else {
      classes[this.className]=1;
    }
});
```

**Snippet,**

```js
var classes = {};
$('[class^=dis_]').each(function() {
  if (classes.hasOwnProperty(this.className)) { // if classs exists then increment it by 1
    classes[this.className] = classes[this.className]+1;
  } else {
    classes[this.className] = 1; // first instance
  }
});
console.log(classes);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dis_1">Class 1</div>
<div class="dis_1">Class 1</div>
<div class="dis_1">Class 1</div>
<div class="dis_5">Class 5</div>
<div class="dis_5">Class 5</div>
<div class="dis_2">Class 2</div>
<div class="dis_3">Class 3</div>
```

If you are having multiple classes then try the below **snippet**

```js
var classes = {};
$('[class*=dis_]').each(function() { // use *= selector, dis_ class can be used anywhere
  className = null;
  // get all classes and split to get match for dis_
  $.each($(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/), function(index, cls) {
    if (/dis_\d+/.test(cls)) {
      className = cls;
    }
  });
  // check if element having class started with dis_
  if (className) {
    if (classes.hasOwnProperty(className)) { // if classs exists then increment it by 1
      classes[className] = classes[className] + 1;
    } else {
      classes[className] = 1; // first instance
    }
  }
});
console.log(classes);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dis_1">Class 1</div>
<div class="dis_1">Class 1</div>
<div class="dis_1 rehub_meta_field rehub_field_1 disabled disabled-0">Class 1</div>
<div class="dis_5">Class 5</div>
<div class="dis_5">Class 5</div>
<div class="dis_2">Class 2</div>
<div class="rehub_meta_field rehub_field_1 disabled disabled-0 dis_3">Class 3</div>
```

Comment: Why you used this.className . It working here but console.log is empty for me don't know why

Comment: my div has multiple classes <div class="rehub_meta_field rehub_field_1 disabled  disabled-0 dis_10">

Comment: Read about className here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className

Comment: Yeah I searched it .thnx.......I think is there sumthing to do with multiple classes

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
var lengthArr = []; // array to hold your result set

var YourNumberLimit = 5; // if you class is an incremental number with prefix "dis_", like dis_1, dis_2, dis_3, dis_4, dis_5

for (i=1;i<=YourNumberLimit ; i++) {

   lengthArr.push ( $(".dis_" + i).length); // your answer is here.

}
```

If this is not your case and you need to calculating length for induvidual classes, then use like this,

```
var lenthOfDis3 = $(".dis_5").length;
var lenthOfDis5 = $(".dis_5").length;
var lenthOfDis7 = $(".dis_5").length;
var lenthOfDis18 = $(".dis_5").length;
```

Comment: I want to count classes indivdually like all dis_2 together , dis_17 together plus there is no limit to the number at the ened

Comment: Then use like this induvidually on each tag. var LengthDis5 =  $(".dis_5").length;

Answer (score 2):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var classString = "";
  jQuery('[class^=dis_]').each(function(){
   var classData = jQuery(this).attr("class");
   var ClassDataChunk = classData.split("_");
   var classChunk = ClassDataChunk[1];
   var elmVal = jQuery("#elm").val();
   if (elmVal.indexOf(classChunk) < 0) {
    alert("Class dis_"+classChunk+" has count = " +jQuery(".dis_"+classChunk).length);
   }
   classString = classString + "," + classChunk;
   jQuery("#elm").val(classString);
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" value="" name="elm" id="elm">
<div class="container">
 <div class="dis_3">3</div>
 <div class="dis_1">1</div>
 <div class="dis_1">1</div>
 <div class="dis_1">1</div>
 <div class="dis_1">1</div>
 <div class="dis_2">2</div>
 <div class="dis_2">2</div>
 <div class="dis_4">4</div>
 <div class="dis_3">3</div>
 <div class="dis_3">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Hope this helps

```js
  
  var arrClasses = [], uniqueClass = [];
$('[class^=dis_]').each(function () {
    var className = this.className.match(/dis_\d+/); 
    if (className) {
        arrClasses.push(className[0]); 
        return className[0]; 
    }
});
$.each(arrClasses, function(i, el){
   if($.inArray(el, uniqueClass) === -1) uniqueClass.push(el);
});
$.each(uniqueClass, function(i, el){
   var classLen = $('.'+el).length;
   console.log('Class: '+ el +'--- Length: '+ classLen);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <body >
<div class="dis_2">1</div>
<div class="dis_2">2</div>
<div class="dis_2">3</div>
<div class="dis_5">4</div>
<div class="dis_5">5</div>
<div class="dis_3">6</div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.from()` with `$("[class*='dis_']")` as parameter, `Array.prototype.reduce()` with plain object of `Map` at second parameter, to set `"dis_N"` as property of object with value set to the matched `.className` with `RegExp` `/dis_\d+/`, which is also passed to `jQuery()` call concatenated to `"."`, with `.length` chained.

```js
var len = Array.from($("[class*='dis_']"))
          .reduce(function(o, el) {
            var c = el.className.match(/dis_\d+/).pop();
            o[c] = $("." + c).length;
            return o
          }, {});

console.log(len);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="abc dis_1"></div>
<div class="dis_2 def"></div>
<div class="ghi dis_2"></div>
<div class="dis_3 jkl"></div>
<div class="mno dis_4"></div>
<div class="dis_2 pqr stu v w xy z"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
  
$(function(){
  var classes = {};
  $('[class^=dis_]').each(function(index,item){
  var reg = /\s*dis_\w+/g;
  var className = $(item).attr('class');
  var regElements = className.match(reg);
      
  for(var i=0;i<regElements.length;i++){
    var matchClassName = $.trim(regElements[i])
    if(classes.hasOwnProperty(matchClassName)){
      classes[matchClassName] += 1;
        }else{
       classes[matchClassName] = 1;
      }
    }
    })
    console.log(classes)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dis_1">Class 1</div>
<div class="dis_1 test">Class 1</div>
<div class="dis_1 dis_5 disable">Class 1</div>
<div class="dis_5 dis_2">Class 5</div>
<div class="dis_5">Class 5</div>
<div class="dis_2">Class 2</div>
<div class="">Class 3</div>
```

Answer (score -4):

Using Jquery .length will return you count of selected element